# Using Python Tweetpy to post message to Twitter

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I have developed a python script to post message to my twitter account.

My post was successfully posted and I can see the post in my twitter account. But I got the following error message from my script in my backend despite the post was successfully posted to Twitter.

```
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
187 - Status is a duplicate.
```

Just wonder if this is a common know issue.

I am posting a daily message with a bottom half of the content being standard explanation. The top line of the content is newly generated and is difference every time. So the 187 duplicate message is somewhat understandable cause Twitter may think I am purposely changing some of my text to post repeat content. But 403 Forbidden does not make sense. May be some of my codes are not needed? Perhaps I am getting 403 because I got 187 in the first place? Here are part of my codes:

```
    twitter_auth_keys = {
        "consumer_key"        : api_key,
        "consumer_secret"     : api_key_secret,
        "access_token"        : access_token,
        "access_token_secret" : access_token_secret
    }

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
            twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
            twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
            )
    auth.set_access_token(
            twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
            twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
            )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    if imgurl != "":
        tempfile= '/content/temp.png'
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
        request = requests.get(imgurl, stream=True, headers = headers)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            with open(tempfile, 'wb') as image:
                for chunk in request:
                    image.write(chunk)
            media = api.media_upload(tempfile)
            os.remove(tempfile)
            status = api.update_status(status=tweetcontent, media_ids=[media.media_id])
    if imgfile != "":
        media = api.media_upload(imgfile)
        status = api.update_status(status=tweetcontent, media_ids=[media.media_id])
    else:
        status = api.update_status(status=tweetcontent)
    return(status)
```